# How can I tell gnuplot to show more digits for ytics?

Tags: gnuplot

I have a set of data that varies in the eight digit. My data looks like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
 Electrostatic Potential
------------------------------------------------------------
Position (um), Potential (V)
                   0,     -0.0397018620551
    0.00713979294463,     -0.0397018617044
     0.0142081879598,     -0.0397018613574
     0.0212058990249,      -0.039701861014
     0.0281336329792,     -0.0397018606745
     0.0349920895941,     -0.0397018603389
     0.0417819616428,     -0.0397018600072
      0.048503934971,     -0.0397018596795
     0.0551586885659,     -0.0397018593558
     0.0617468946249,     -0.0397018590363
     0.0682692186233,     -0.0397018587208
     0.0747263193817,     -0.0397018584096
     0.0811188491325,     -0.0397018581026
     0.0874474535858,     -0.0397018577998
```

And, as said, it varies very slowly in the eight digit. When I plot it I get the following picture:

[image: bad yaxis values]

As you can see, the ytics don't show all the digits and the same value repeats a few times. This makes a bit difficult to read it correctly.

I there a way I can put more digits in the vertical axis?
Or, if you have any suggestions for displaying the data in a good-looking way, I would be gratefull.

This is my gnuplot code this far:

```
set title font ",14"

set xlabel font ",14"
set xtics font ",14"
set ylabel font ",14"
set ytics font ",12"
set key font ",14"

#set key at 0.65, -3.5
set lmargin 17
set bmargin 5
set ylabel offset -3.5,0,0
set ylabel "Tensión (mV) "
set xlabel 'Longitud ({/Symbol m}m)'

plot 'G=1e20.txt' u 1:($2*100000) title 'G = 1e20 cm^{-3}', \
'G=2e20.txt' u 1:($2*100000) title 'G = 2e20 cm^{-3}', \
'G=5e20.txt' u 1:($2*100000) title 'G = 5e20 cm^{-3}', \
'G=10e20.txt' u 1:($2*100000) title 'G = 10e20 cm^{-3}',
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a format with the `set ytics` eg:

```
set ytics font ",12"    format "%.5f"
```

which asks for 5 digits of precision in a float format.